# How can I prove big-oh relation between $\log_2(\log_2 n)$ and $\sqrt{\log_2 n}$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

How can I prove big-O relation between $f=\log_2(\log_2 n)$ and $g=\sqrt{\log_2 n}\,$?

I want to find the constants, $c, N$ such that $\ g(x) \leq cf(x)$ for all $x>N$.

Comment: First you can find when $\log_2\log_2 N=\sqrt{\log_2 N}$. What happens if you take $x>N$ after that?

Comment: A useful result, if $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{g(n)}{f(n)}=a$, then $g=O(f)$.

Comment: As an additional comment, you need only check the relation between $\log_2x$ and $\sqrt x$. You may solve for $c,N'$ in this case let $N=2^{N'}$.

Comment: You can't. Did you mean $f(x) \le c g(x)$?

Comment: @FrankMcGovern I fail to see the point of solving $\log_2x=\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of the usual logarithm function is less than $1$ on $(1,+\infty)$ hence $\ln x\leqslant x-1$ on $x\geqslant1$. This implies $\log_2x\leqslant2x$ on $x\geqslant1$. Since $\log_2x=2\log_2\sqrt{x}$, $\log_2x\leqslant4\sqrt{x}$ on $x\geqslant1$.

Appplying this to $x=\log_2n$, one sees that $f(n)\leqslant4g(n)$ for every $n\geqslant2$.